# How do I conditionally resize an image using GraphicsMagick?

Tags: subprocess, imagemagick, image-resizing, graphicsmagick, mogrify

I am using the mogrify command. Here is my command (as a list in Python). Everything is fine except for the resize command.

```
            ["gm" ,'mogrify',
                '-format', 'png',
                '-units', 'PixelsPerInch',
                '-create-directories',
                '-density', '600',
                '-sharpen', '1', 
                '-monochrome', 
                '-bordercolor', 'white',
                '-border' ,'10' ,
                '-background', 'white', 
                '-output-directory', <output_directory>,
                '-resize', '600x600<250%',
                "*"]
```

I am trying to say "if both image dimensions are smaller than 600 pixels, increase both dimensions by 250%."

Here's the error:

```
File "C:\Users\mynam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 512, in run
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args,
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['gm', 'mogrify', '-format', 'png', '-units', 
'PixelsPerInch', '-create-directories', '-density', '600', '-sharpen', '1', '-monochrome', '-bordercolor', 'white', '-border', '10', '-background', 'white', '-output-directory', '../MagnusWhiteOutput', '-geometry', '640x640\\\\>', '*']' **returned non-zero exit status 1.**
```

I get the same error when I omit the "250%" at the end of the command, i.e. I just try '-resize', '600x600<', which is extremely similar to examples from the documentation.

Note that the code does what I want (except for the resizing) when I omit the resize command altogether, so the problem cannot be anywhere else in the code.

Update: changing the argument to '-resize', '250 600<%' makes it resize by 250%, but it completely ignores the 600. If I put in a 610x610 image, it just resizes it by 250%.

Comment: You can't just make up your own options. I would check the image size outside your gm code, work out the values then feed the variables in to your gm code

Comment: that's not helpful.

Comment: @EthanSeal Can you share a link to the documentation you're using? I want to make sure I'm looking at the right thing.

Comment: @AMC http://www.graphicsmagick.org/mogrify.html 

http://www.graphicsmagick.org/GraphicsMagick.html#details-resize

I use the mogrify command with a resize argument.

Comment: _I get the same error when I omit the "250%" at the end of the command, i.e. I just try '-resize', '600x600<', which is extremely similar to examples from the documentation._ That's quite strange. The error shows the argument as `'640x640\\\\>'`, so could it be an issue related to escaping characters? Can you run these from the command line without any issue?